# how to get teechart activex on Qt

Tags: qt, mfc, activex, teechart

I am currently working on a project where TeeChart Pro ActiveX 2012 is used with Visual C++ and MFC.Now i want to move my project to cross platform language Qt.I have searched a lot on Qt forums but didn't get a proper sample code to display Teechart in Qt.I shall be highly thankful if someone could give me a sample code or proper workaround to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but we don't have any QT example. You can use ActiveX controls in QT but only Windows, not for X-platform applications. This might be your problem. Have you managed to use other ActiveX controls? All TeeChart options in QT were discussed [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11850#p50784).